# JDA - Bot listens to other bots reactions

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, discord-jda

for some reason my bot listens to all other bots reactions.

Example: If I had a random giveaway bot in my server which uses reactions to join it, my bot will listen to this random bots reactions for some odd reason.

Here is my reactionListener;

```
public void onGuildMessageReactionAdd(GuildMessageReactionAddEvent e) {
        if (e.getUser().isBot()) return;

        e.retrieveMessage().queue(message -> {
            if (message.getAuthor().getIdLong() != ProjectWar.getInstance().getDiscord().getJda().getSelfUser().getIdLong()) return;
            if (!e.getMember().hasPermission(Permission.ADMINISTRATOR)) {
                DiscordUtils.noPerm(e.getMember(), message);
                e.getChannel().removeReactionById(e.getMessageId(), e.getReactionEmote().getName(), e.getUser()).queue();
                return;
            }
            for (MessageEmbed embed : message.getEmbeds()) {
                for (MessageEmbed.Field field : embed.getFields()) {
                    switch (field.getName()) {
                        case "Player":
                            this.reporter = field.getValue();
                            break;
                        case "FactionOne":
                            factionOne = field.getValue();
                            break;
                        case "FactionTwo":
                            this.factionTwo = field.getValue();
                            break;
                        case "ID":
                            this.ID = Integer.parseInt(field.getValue());
                            break;
                        case "Reason":
                            this.reason = field.getValue();
                            break;
                        case "State":
                            this.state = field.getValue();
                            break;
                        case "Date":
                            this.date = ProjectWar.getInstance().parse(field.getValue());
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            WarReport report = new WarReport(reporter, factionOne, factionTwo, reason, (ID + 1), date, state);

            MessageReaction reaction = message.getReactions().stream()
                    .filter(r -> r.getReactionEmote().getName().equals(e.getReactionEmote().getName()))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(null);

            if (reaction != null) {
                if (reaction.getCount() > 2) {
                    e.getChannel().removeReactionById(e.getMessageId(), e.getReactionEmote().getName(), e.getUser()).queue();
                }
            }
            //todo: convert to class with emotes.
            if (e.getReactionEmote().getName().equals("\uD83D\uDDD1")) {
                ReportManager.removeReport(report);
                e.getChannel().deleteMessageById(e.getMessageId()).queue();
            } else if (e.getReactionEmote().getName().equals("❌")) {
                ProjectWar.getInstance().getDiscord().editStatus(e.getMessageId(), e.getChannel(), false);
                ReportManager.setReportState(report, false);
            } else if (e.getReactionEmote().getName().equals("✅")) {
                ProjectWar.getInstance().getDiscord().editStatus(e.getMessageId(), e.getChannel(), true);
                ReportManager.setReportState(report, true);
            }
        });
    }
    
    // no perm method
    public static void noPerm(Member member, Message message) {
        EmbedBuilder embedBuilder = new EmbedBuilder().setColor(Color.RED).setTitle("Missing permission!");
        embedBuilder.addField("", "You're not allowed to do that <@" + member.getId() + ">!", false);
        message.getChannel().sendMessage(embedBuilder.build()).queue(message1 -> message1.delete().queueAfter(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    }
```

How would I make it so my bot only listens to messages sent from my own bot?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error is somewhere else. I may be wrong but I couldn't find the error inside your code.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to check if the message that someone reacted to has been sent by your bot.
To do that you will have to get the Message that someone reacted to first.

```
Message msg = e.getChannel().retrieveMessageById(e.getMessageId()).complete();
```

Then you can easily check if that message has been sent by your bot:

```
if (msg.getAuthor().equals(e.getJDA().getSelfUser())) {
    // message that someone reacted to has been sent by your bot
}
```

Comment: You should probably retrieve the message using e.retrieveMessage(), but it does the same.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will return if the user that reacted is not the currently running instance.

```java
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.react.GuildMessageReactionAddEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class Example extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onGuildMessageReactionAdd(GuildMessageReactionAddEvent event) {
        if (event.getUser().getIdLong() != event.getJDA().getSelfUser().getIdLong()) return;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You are now checking if the user that added the reaction is the self user: you want to check for the owner of the message is the self user.